# get only a value with Quandl in Python

Tags: python-3.x, quandl

I'm working with Quandl. I had search in the documentation but I cant find it

```
import quandl

quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = 'PNPLwChDhr6UMUVvfc5h'
gold = quandl.get('LBMA/GOLD', rows=1, column_index='2')

print(gold)
```

When I run it, the console shows:

```
  USD (PM)
Date                
2020-08-13   1944.25
```

But, I only need it `1944.25` to compare it then with an `if` statement.
How can print only the specific value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code:

```
import quandl

quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = 'your-api-key'
gold = quandl.get('LBMA/GOLD', rows=1, column_index='2')

print(gold.iloc[0].values[0])
```

Output:

```
1944.75
```